# What hardware/software do I need to connect to SWD on an NXP LPC820 ARM MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, debugging, swd

I have a Li-po battery pack that I'd like to debug. The on-board BMS has an [NXP LPC820](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-microcontrollers/general-purpose-mcus/lpc800-arm-cortex-m0-plus-/lpc820-32-bit-arm-cortexm0-plus-based-low-cost-mcu:LPC82X) MCU and I've identified the SWD header.

My reason for doing this is that one of the 5 cells went bad, which I've replaced and charged to match the others, but the BMS seems to have some sort of error code stored and the manufacturer wants $100+ for a new one). I have  a "good" pack and a "bad" pack, so would be interested to read the NVRAM and compare.

Now, my professional experience is only using ST MCUs, and for that I would use an STLINK v2 (latest firmware) and the STLINK utility to interface to those devices. However, when I try and connect to this LPC820 device using STLINK, it comes back with an "unknown device" error, which I assume is because it's not an ST MCU. But it's positive it seems to know something is connected (i.e. the pins are active on the board).

I am just interested if I can read the firmware from this device. I have tried searching for what I need, but it's very confusing what hardware and software I would need for this LXP chip. If there is some software that would work with the STLINK v2 then that would be great.

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/671732/363515) seems to be a similar (but not identical) board, and someone managed to connect, so hopefully it's not locked.

Comment: Even if you manage to communicate with the MCU somehow, be prepared for the fact that the MCU might have enabled readout protection to prevent tampering with the pack.

Comment: The _Code security (Code Read Protection - CRP)_ section of the LPC82x datasheet linked in the question notes that it possible to disable access to the chip via the SWD interface. If Code Read Protection is enabled, without further research, I'm not sure if STLINK would report "unknown device" or some other error.

Comment: @Justme yes I am aware of that possibility being quite likely given the potential safety risks. But, I did find someone that had been successful on something similar (added link to the original question), so I am a little bit hopeful that if I get the right software/hardware I might be able to read it.